# Casting a double as an int, does it round or just strip digits?

Tags: c#, casting, int, double, rounding

Doing some calculations with doubles which then need to be cast to an int. So i have a quick question, when casting a double say 7.5 to an int, it will return 7.

Is this a product of rounding or just striping anything after the decimal point?

If it is a product of rounding, is it smart ie 0.1 to 0.5 it rounds down and 0.6 to 0.9 it rounds up?

Cheers

Comment: A bit of quick experimentation would have answered this question...

Comment: Writing two lines of code to test by yourself may have been quicker than posting the question here...

Comment: check it yourself: `int num = (int) 7.8; Console.WriteLine(num);`

Comment: Why not make it explicit (so future programmers don't have to wonder) and use `Math.Floor` to strip off the decimals, and then cast?

Comment: Well I'm new to C# so I'm asking about absolutely everything to be honest.

Comment: @cosmicsafari you can learn a lot from experimentation.

Comment: @AnnL.: Casting to int is not the same as floor. Floor rounds towards minus infinity. Casting rounds to zero. This gives a different result for negative numbers.

Comment: @MarkByers  Good point re. rounding.

Comment: @AnnL.: You could use Math.Truncate though, if you wanted to be explicit.

Comment: @JonB true, but i can also learn alot from asking and experimenting :p

Comment: @cosmicsafari Asking questions of others takes up a lot of their time and effort, of which they are freely giving up.  It is curious to spent some time and effort attempting to solve your problems on your own by doing some simple tests, doing some research into the issue (it is well documented and easily accessible online to determine the C# mechanic for casting a double to a float), etc.  When you spend absolutely no time trying to solve your own problem and just go straight to others it is rude, and also becomes a crutch for you as you don't learn how to solve your own problems.

Comment: I'm personally glad he asked this question so I could find the answer quickly.  I had a hunch that it was always rounding down but I appreciate this question for the quick confirmation.  experimentation is good but this question saved me the trouble.

Comment: @Ray L Seriously.. I don't understand the commenters, this is one of the major points of the site. 2 Years after the question was asked and this is the top result from googling the question "Which way does int round" and it's no thanks to the people angry that OP could've found out the answer himself.

Comment: @RayLoveless & CsharpFrustration: Nobody is criticizing you for trying to conduct research on your own (whether it be thru experimentation or a web search.) They're criticizing OP for not showing any attempt at research, which is one of the cardinal rules for asking questions here. Go re-ask this question and see what kind of response you get. SO was never intended to be a crutch for the lazy. Especially when it concerns easily accessible information.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It does not round, it just returns the integral part before the decimal point.

Reference (thanks [Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215380/rawling)) [**Explicit Numeric Conversions Table**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx):

> When you convert a double or float value to an integral type, this
>   value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value.

You can try simple issues like this by yourself by writing simple tests. The following test (using [NUnit](http://nunit.org/)) will pass and therefore give an answer to your question:

```
[Test]
public void Cast_float_to_int_will_not_round_but_truncate
{
    var x = 3.9f;
    Assert.That((int)x == 3); // <-- This will pass
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Don't be fooled by assuming it rounds down.  It strips the decimal off and purely returns the integer portion of the double.  This is important with negative numbers because rounding down from 2.75 gives you 2, but rounding down from -2.75 give you -3.  Casting does not round down so (int)2.75 gives 2, but (int)-2.75 gives you -2.

```
double positiveDouble = 2.75;
double negativeDouble = -2.75;

int positiveInteger = (int) positiveDouble;
int negativeInteger = (int) negativeDouble;

Console.WriteLine(positiveInteger + " = (int)" + positiveDouble);
Console.WriteLine(negativeInteger + " = (int)" + negativeDouble);

Console.ReadLine();

//Output: 2 = (int)2.75
//        -2 = (int)-2.75
```

Answer (score 16):

Simply casting just strips everything past the decimal point. To round up or down, you can use the [Math.Round() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx). This will round up or down and provides a parameter on what to do if its midway. You could also use the [Math.Floor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx) or [Math.Ceiling()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) methods to implicitly round up or round down prior to casting. Here are some examples:

```
double num1 = 3.5;
double num2 = 3.2;
double num3 = 3.9;

(int)num1 // returns 3;
(int)num2 // returns 3;
(int)num3 // returns 3 also;
(int)Math.Round(num1) // returns 4
(int)Math.Round(num2) // returns 3
(int)Math.Round(num3) // returns 4
(int)Math.Floor(num1) // returns 3
(int)Math.Floor(num2) // returns 3
(int)Math.Floor(num3) // returns 3
(int)Math.Ceiling(num1) // returns 4
(int)Math.Ceiling(num2) // returns 4;
(int)Math.Ceiling(num3) // returns 4;
```

Answer (score 5):

It takes the integer part

```
double d = 0.9;
System.Console.WriteLine((int)d);
```

the result is 0

Answer (score 2):

A normal cast like this

```
int number;
double decimals = 7.8987;

number = (int)decimals;
```

will return number = 7. That is because it just skips the least significant numbers. If you want it to round properly you can use **Math.Round()** like this:

```
number = (int)Math.Round(number);
```

This will return number = 8.

Answer (score 1):

From the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> In an `unchecked` context, the conversion always succeeds, and
>   proceeds as follows.
>
> • If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite,
>   the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the
>   destination type.
>
> • Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards
>   zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within
>   the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the
>   conversion.
>
> • Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an
>   unspecified value of the destination type.

See also [Explicit Numeric Conversions Table — Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

If it's returning 7 for a double of 7.5, then it isn't rounding, because rounding rules would dictate that anything 5 and above rounds up, not down.

Comment: Unless the underlying value isn't 7.5 but 7.49999999999 in which case it may display 7.5 on the screen, but round to 7.  These types of issues happen a lot due to floating point precision issues.  The OP specifically wondered if that was the actual cause of his issue.  Now, it's not, but it was a perfectly valid concern.  Testing the code by converting 7.7d to an int is not nearly as ambiguous.

Comment: @Servy (and Brian) Also, there will be `double` numbers like `7.9999999999999991` whose default string representations are `"8"`, but which are truncated to integer `7` with the cast syntax.

Comment: This should be a comment.